# Exporting Spring Boot Actuator Metrics (& Dropwizard Metrics) to Statsd

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

I'm trying to export all of the metrics which are visible at the endpoint `/metrics` to a `StatsdMetricWriter`.

I've got the following configuration class so far:

```
package com.tonyghita.metricsdriven.service.config;

import com.codahale.metrics.MetricRegistry;
import com.ryantenney.metrics.spring.config.annotation.EnableMetrics;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.ExportMetricReader;
import org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.ExportMetricWriter;
import org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.reader.MetricReader;
import org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.reader.MetricRegistryMetricReader;
import org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.statsd.StatsdMetricWriter;
import org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.writer.MetricWriter;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;


@Configuration
@EnableMetrics(proxyTargetClass = true)
public class MetricsConfig {
    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MetricsConfig.class);

    @Value("${statsd.host:localhost}")
    private String host = "localhost";

    @Value("${statsd.port:8125}")
    private int port;

    @Autowired
    private MetricRegistry metricRegistry;

    @Bean
    @ExportMetricReader
    public MetricReader metricReader() {
        return new MetricRegistryMetricReader(metricRegistry);
    }

    @Bean
    @ExportMetricWriter
    public MetricWriter metricWriter() {
        LOGGER.info("Configuring StatsdMetricWriter to export to {}:{}", host, port);
        return new StatsdMetricWriter(host, port);
    }
}
```

Which writes all of the metrics which I've added to Statsd, but I'd like to also send the system/JVM metrics that are visible on the `/metrics` endpoint.

What am I missing?

Comment: Maybe [this PR](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/pull/3719) (pending merge) would help

Comment: Hope that gets merged @StéphaneNicoll! That change adds convenience around setting up the Statsd writer, but my question is more along the lines of how to set up an `@ExportMetricReader` bean that exports the metrics available at the `/metrics` endpoint.

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem and found a solution here: https://github.com/tzolov/export-metrics-example

Just add a `MetricsEndpointMetricReader` to your config and everything available at th e/metrics endpoint will be published to the `StatsdMetricWriter`.

Here is a complete example config for spring boot 1.3.x and dropwizard metrics-jvm 3.1.x:

```java
import com.codahale.metrics.MetricRegistry;
import com.codahale.metrics.jvm.GarbageCollectorMetricSet;
import com.codahale.metrics.jvm.MemoryUsageGaugeSet;
import com.codahale.metrics.jvm.ThreadStatesGaugeSet;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.ExportMetricWriter;
import org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.MetricsEndpoint;
import org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.MetricsEndpointMetricReader;
import org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.Metric;
import org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.statsd.StatsdMetricWriter;
import org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.writer.Delta;
import org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.writer.MetricWriter;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.ConditionalOnMissingBean;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.ConditionalOnProperty;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
public class MetricsConfiguration {

  @Bean
  public MetricRegistry metricRegistry() {
    final MetricRegistry metricRegistry = new MetricRegistry();

    metricRegistry.register("jvm.memory",new MemoryUsageGaugeSet());
    metricRegistry.register("jvm.thread-states",new ThreadStatesGaugeSet());
    metricRegistry.register("jvm.garbage-collector",new GarbageCollectorMetricSet());

    return metricRegistry;
  }

  /*
   * Reading all metrics that appear on the /metrics endpoint to expose them to metrics writer beans.
   */
  @Bean
  public MetricsEndpointMetricReader metricsEndpointMetricReader(final MetricsEndpoint metricsEndpoint) {
    return new MetricsEndpointMetricReader(metricsEndpoint);
  }

  @Bean
  @ConditionalOnProperty(prefix = "statsd", name = {"prefix", "host", "port"})
  @ExportMetricWriter
  public MetricWriter statsdMetricWriter(@Value("${statsd.prefix}") String statsdPrefix,
                                     @Value("${statsd.host}") String statsdHost,
                                     @Value("${statsd.port}") int statsdPort) {
    return new StatsdMetricWriter(statsdPrefix, statsdHost, statsdPort);
  }

}
```

Answer (score 5):

From what I've seen in spring-boot code, only calls to `CounterService` and `GaugeService` implementations are forwarded to dropwizard's `MetricRegistry`.

Therefore, as you already observed, only `counter.*` and `gauge.*` metrics from the `/metrics` endpoint will end up in `Statsd`.

System and JVM metrics are exposed through custom `SystemPublicMetrics` class, which doesn't use counter or gauge service.

I'm not sure if there is a simpler solution (maybe someone from Spring team will comment), but one way to do it (not spring-boot specific) would be to use a scheduled task that periodically writes system stats to the `MetricRegistry`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @mzc. I would've loved to use the existing `SystemPublicMetrics`, but as you pointed out, it is not so straightforward. Fortunately, there is a `'io.dropwizard.metrics:metrics-jvm'` library that handles exporting jvm metrics nicely. I'd still like to export those nice tomcat metrics though, so it may be valuable to explore that solution you proposed.

Answer (score 5):

To register JVM metrics you can use the JVM related MetricSets supplied by codehale.metrics.jvm library. You can just add the whole set without supplying whether they are gauges or counters.

Here is my example code where I am registering jvm related metrics:

```
@Configuration
@EnableMetrics(proxyTargetClass = true)
public class MetricsConfig {

@Autowired
private StatsdProperties statsdProperties;

@Autowired
private MetricsEndpoint metricsEndpoint;

@Autowired
private DataSourcePublicMetrics dataSourcePublicMetrics;

@Bean
@ExportMetricReader
public MetricReader metricReader() {
    return new MetricRegistryMetricReader(metricRegistry());
}

public MetricRegistry metricRegistry() {
    final MetricRegistry metricRegistry = new MetricRegistry();

    //jvm metrics
    metricRegistry.register("jvm.gc",new GarbageCollectorMetricSet());
    metricRegistry.register("jvm.mem",new MemoryUsageGaugeSet());
    metricRegistry.register("jvm.thread-states",new ThreadStatesGaugeSet());

    return metricRegistry;
}

@Bean
@ConditionalOnProperty(prefix = "metrics.writer.statsd", name = {"host", "port"})
@ExportMetricWriter
public MetricWriter statsdMetricWriter() {
    return new StatsdMetricWriter(
            statsdProperties.getPrefix(),
            statsdProperties.getHost(),
            statsdProperties.getPort()
    );
}
```

}

Note: I am using spring boot version 1.3.0.M4

Comment: Thanks for your answer @YonatanWilcof. Looks like we're on the same version of Spring Boot. 


I was able to get the JVM metrics like you described by adding `'io.dropwizard.metrics:metrics-jvm:3.1.2'` to my dependencies, and registering `GarbageCollectorMetricSet`, `MemoryUsageGaugeSet`, and `ThreadStatesGaugeSet` to the `metricRegistry`.

I was hoping to be able to use the existing `SystemPublicMetrics` mechanism, but this also gets the job done.

Looks like there is also a `metrics-jdbi` library! Time to dig in to that :)

Comment: I think the last piece for me would be to figure out how to add tomcat/endpoint stats to the registry.

Comment: @Yonatan Wilkof: which jar does the 'StatsdProperties' class gets imported from, I don't seem to have it within 'io.dropwizard.metrics',  'com.ryantenney.metrics' and 'spring-boot-starter-actuator'.  Do I need to add something else to my pom.xml?  Thanks.

Comment: it does not belong to a library, just a class that is mapped with properties. It's inspired by the PR https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/pull/3719 posted as a comment to the original question.

Answer (score 4):

Enjoy! (see the public metrics logged in console as dropwizard metrics)

```
@Configuration
@EnableMetrics
@EnableScheduling
public class MetricsReporter extends MetricsConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired private SystemPublicMetrics systemPublicMetrics;
    private MetricRegistry metricRegistry;

    @Scheduled(fixedDelay = 5000)
    void exportPublicMetrics() {
        for (Metric<?> metric : systemPublicMetrics.metrics()) {
            Counter counter = metricRegistry.counter(metric.getName());
            counter.dec(counter.getCount());
            counter.inc(Double.valueOf(metric.getValue().toString()).longValue());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void configureReporters(MetricRegistry metricRegistry) {
        this.metricRegistry = metricRegistry;
        ConsoleReporter.forRegistry(metricRegistry).build().start(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks @CelinHC, I'll have to give this solution a shot when I get some time

Comment: Another, arguably cleaner way is described here:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/42933115/716720

Comment: @SergeyShcherbakov  Unfortunately spring guys think it's LOW. https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/4197